# PHPからmb_send_mailを利用してメール送信した場合の、NDRの確認方法

Tags: php, sendmail

PHP内から、`mb_send_mail`を利用してメール送信しています。

```
mb_send_mail("address@test.com", "TEST", "Message", "From: someone");
```

もし`address@test.com`が間違っていた場合、もしくは何らかの理由で相手先に弾かれて、NDRが返信されてきている場合、そのメールはどうやって確認できるのでしょうか。
または、送信されたメールに返信した場合、そのメールはどこに格納されるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

配送に失敗した場合のエラーはメールのenvelope from宛に通知されます。メールのFrom: ヘッダではなく、SMTPのMAIL From:コマンドで指定されるアドレスです。

`mb_send_mail()`(`mail()`のラッパー)はシステムのsendmailコマンドを使ってメールを送信しますので、envelope fromが何になるかはその設定次第です。ユーザー名@ホスト名(FQDN)になるのが一般的ではないでしょうか。

`mb_send_mail()`(`mail()`)の第5引数で`sendmail`コマンドに渡すオプションを指定できるので、システムの`sendmail`コマンドが対応していれば`-f foo@example.jp`を指定することでenvelope fromを任意のアドレスに設定することができます。

Comment: 第5引数に-f foo@example.jpを挿入することで、解決いたしました。
ありがとうございました。